# How do I highlight pc-lint comments in C/C++

Tags: syntax-highlighting, comments, filetype-c

How do I mimic the behavior of Doxygen comment highlighting for PC-lint comments? Comments are in the following formats:

```
/*lint ... */
//lint ...
/* LINTLIBRARY */
/* ARGUSED */
/* VARARGS[N] */ <--- N is a number
/* NOTREACHED */
/* NOSTRICT */
/* FALLTHROUGH */
/* FALLTHRU */
/* PRINTFLIKEN */ <--- N is a number
```

Ideally highlighting would mimic the behavior of Doxygen comment highlighting.

EDIT: I want to make lint comments highlight like the Doxygen comment in the screenshot.
[image: like this]

Comment: Do you want the above to be simply highlighted as comments or is there additional nested highlighting that you want? If it's the latter, a screen-shot might help.

Comment: @Tumbler41 I want to highlight the listed keywords in the comments just like Doxygen commands are highlighted.

Comment: Maybe I'm in the minority, but I don't know how Doxygen commands are highlighted, and a quick google search produced nothing useful. Could you provide a screenshot with the appropriate highlighting you're looking for?

Answer (score 3):

Did you have a look at `syntax/doxygen.vim`? This is where doxygen highlighting is defined.

What you need to do then, is to add a file for pclint in `~/.vim/syntax/`, and a syntax rule inspired from the one in `syntax/synload.vim` which is:

```
au Syntax c,cpp,cs,idl,java,php,datascript
    \ if (exists('b:load_doxygen_syntax') && b:load_doxygen_syntax)
    \   || (exists('g:load_doxygen_syntax') && g:load_doxygen_syntax)
    \   | runtime! syntax/doxygen.vim
    \ | endif
```

See [`:h mysyntaxfile`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#mysyntaxfile)